# show vector $b$ is in the column space of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I come up with following two equations $\,c,w\in \mathbb{R}\:q,b\in\mathbb R^{m}, A$ is $m\times m$ matrix, and $p$ is a $1\times m$ vector. I am trying to show that $b\in  Col(A)$

$$
c+q^Tb=w\implies q^Tb=w-c\\
q^TA=p\implies q^T=pA^{-1}\\
\text{by substituttion}\quad pA^{-1}b=(w-c)
$$

End up here I have no idea how to proceed further, I felt there is some technique that can put $A^{-1}$ on the right-hand side.

Sincerely thank you for your help.

Comment: If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, and if $m\ne n$, then there is no such animal as $A^{-1}$. Only [some] square matrices have inverses.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your reply. Yes, you are right. If $A$ is a square matrix, can my equation proceed further under any technique?

Comment: If $A$ is a square matrix, then please edit your question to say so.

Comment: OK, so even though you don't say it, we're to assume $A$ is an *invertible* matrix. You want to show that there exists $x$ such that $Ax=b$, but all you know about $b$ is that when you multiply it by the transpose of $q$, you get a number (which is to say, you know nothing about $b$, and all you know about $q$ is that when you multiply it by $A$ you get a vector (which is to say, you know nothing about $q$), and you know nothing about $A$ except that it's invertible. Fortunately, that's all you need to know: since $A$ is invertible, its column space is all of ${\bf R}^m$, (continued)

Comment: (continued) so certainly $b$ is in it. All the information about $c,q,w,p$ is superfluous.

Comment: Understood, LJNG?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. Thank you so much. Invertible means their columns are $m$ linearly independent vectors, so it will be the basis of the space$\mathbb{R}^m$, so it spans the whole space.